# Remove a specific global scope in a whereHas model call in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I want to remove the **EmpresaScope** global scope in the **whereHas** call:

```
// $tipoTreinamento is a Eloquent model

$tipoTreinamento->with(['funcaoEmpresa' => function($relation){
    // Here it works
    (new EmpresaScope())->remove($relation->getQuery(), $relation->getRelated());
}])
->whereHas('funcaoEmpresa', function($query) use ($colaborador){
    // Here it doesn't
    (new EmpresaScope())->remove($query, $query->getModel());

    $query->where('id', $colaborador['funcao_empresa_id']);
});
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the **with** and **whereHas** methods doesn't use its closures in a similar way.

Does someone know a way to achieve it?

This is the remove implementation

```
class EmpresaScope implements ScopeInterface
{

 ...

    public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model) 
    {
        // Reference https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/need-help-writing-remove-for-global-query-scope
        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        $bindingKey = 0;
        foreach ($query->wheres as $i => $where)
        {
            if ($where['column'] == $model['table'].'.empresa_id')
            {
                // Remove o where do scope
                unset($query->wheres[$i]);

                // Remove o valor que entraria no where
                $bindings = $query->getBindings();
                unset($bindings[$bindingKey]);
                $query->setBindings($bindings);

                break;
            }

            if ( ! in_array($where['type'], ['Null', 'NotNull'])) $bindingKey++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's working with `with`?  I may be confused but it looks like you aren't actually doing anything inside of that closure.

Comment: Yes, I don't fully understand the mechanics here, but it looks to me that the **$relation** argument in the **with** closure is passed by reference, so any changes you make to it reflects on the original instance.

Comment: That makes sense but the functions which are being called on the `$relation` variable are not changing the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by overriding the relating methods.  I've created a trait for ease of use.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

trait UnscopedRelations
{
    /**
     * Define an inverse one-to-one or many relationship.
     *
     * @param  string  $related
     * @param  string  $foreignKey
     * @param  string  $otherKey
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null, array $removeScopes = [])
    {
        // If no relation name was given, we will use this debug backtrace to extract
        // the calling method's name and use that as the relationship name as most
        // of the time this will be what we desire to use for the relationships.
        if (is_null($relation)) {
            list($current, $caller) = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2);

            $relation = $caller['function'];
        }

        // If no foreign key was supplied, we can use a backtrace to guess the proper
        // foreign key name by using the name of the relationship function, which
        // when combined with an "_id" should conventionally match the columns.
        if (is_null($foreignKey)) {
            $foreignKey = Str::snake($relation).'_id';
        }

        $instance = new $related;

        // Once we have the foreign key names, we'll just create a new Eloquent query
        // for the related models and returns the relationship instance which will
        // actually be responsible for retrieving and hydrating every relations.
        $query = $instance->newQueryWithoutScopes();

        foreach ($instance->getGlobalScopes() as $identifier => $scope) {
            if(in_array($scope, $removeScopes)) {
                continue;
            }

            $query->withGlobalScope($identifier, $scope);
        }

        $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getKeyName();

        return new BelongsTo($query, $this, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
    }

    /**
     * Define a one-to-many relationship.
     *
     * @param  string  $related
     * @param  string  $foreignKey
     * @param  string  $localKey
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null, array $removeScopes = [])
    {
        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $instance = new $related;

        $query = $instance->newQueryWithoutScopes();

        foreach ($instance->getGlobalScopes() as $identifier => $scope) {
            if(in_array($scope, $removeScopes)) {
                continue;
            }

            $query->withGlobalScope($identifier, $scope);
        }

        $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

        return new HasMany($query, $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey);
    }

    /**
     * Define a many-to-many relationship.
     *
     * @param  string  $related
     * @param  string  $table
     * @param  string  $foreignKey
     * @param  string  $otherKey
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null, array $removeScopes = [])
    {
        // If no relationship name was passed, we will pull backtraces to get the
        // name of the calling function. We will use that function name as the
        // title of this relation since that is a great convention to apply.
        if (is_null($relation)) {
            $relation = $this->getBelongsToManyCaller();
        }

        // First, we'll need to determine the foreign key and "other key" for the
        // relationship. Once we have determined the keys we'll make the query
        // instances as well as the relationship instances we need for this.
        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $instance = new $related;

        $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getForeignKey();

        // If no table name was provided, we can guess it by concatenating the two
        // models using underscores in alphabetical order. The two model names
        // are transformed to snake case from their default CamelCase also.
        if (is_null($table)) {
            $table = $this->joiningTable($related);
        }

        // Now we're ready to create a new query builder for the related model and
        // the relationship instances for the relation. The relations will set
        // appropriate query constraint and entirely manages the hydrations.
        $query = $instance->newQueryWithoutScopes();

        foreach ($instance->getGlobalScopes() as $identifier => $scope) {
            if(in_array($scope, $removeScopes)) {
                continue;
            }

            $query->withGlobalScope($identifier, $scope);
        }

        return new BelongsToMany($query, $this, $table, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
    }
}
```

In your models, simply include the trait where you need to modify the scopes when building relations.

```
class TipoTreinamento extends Model
{
    use UnscopedRelations;

    public function FuncaoEmpresa()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FuncaoEmpresa::class, null, null, null, [new EmpresaScope]);
    }
}
```

How this works is whatever scopes you pass in the last parameter of a `belongsTo`, `hasMany`, `hasOne`, or `belongsToMany` function, those scopes will be removed from the queries.

I'd suggest creating additional relating methods for example `FuncaoEmpresaWithoutEmpressaScope()` and then pass the name of that function in your `with` methods where needed.

### Without any global scopes

I see in your comment you were attempting to remove all global scopes.  If that's something you wish to do instead so that you don't need to pass an array of scopes to be removed, it's quite easy to make that change.

In each function in the trait, you will see a portion which looks like this...

```
        $query = $instance->newQueryWithoutScopes();

        foreach ($instance->getGlobalScopes() as $identifier => $scope) {
            if(in_array($scope, $removeScopes)) {
                continue;
            }

            $query->withGlobalScope($identifier, $scope);
        }
```

You should be able to remove the foreach loop portion and it will just create a new query without global scopes each time and you would no longer need to pass an array.

Comment: I think this is a very nice solution, thanks for sharing. I tried to use it, but I need to update my Laravel to 5.2 before, I'm having [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488801/laravel-request-validation-throwing-httpresponseexception-in-version-5-2) problem updating it. As soon as I can test this, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Before you try to implement my solution, I'd try to re-use yours.  There were some improvements made to 5.2 which make global scopes easier to use.

Comment: Indeed, I've already tried using the new `$eloquentBuilder->withoutGlobalScope($scope)`, still not working in `whereHas`. Anyway, using your trait would be better, since there are many cases where we will be removing the global scope in our current project, so the code in our repositories/controllers will be cleaner.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  If you want to just remove all global scopes and not worry about passing an array of scopes to remove, it would be simple and I believe it would also be a solution for 5.1

Comment: Sorry, I could have been more specific. I can't remove all the global scopes, we're using [Soft Deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#soft-deleting) in our models, and it uses a global scope to filter the disabled records.

Answer (score 2):

you can do:

```
$tipoTreinamento->with(['funcaoEmpresa' => function($relation){
    // Here it works
    (new EmpresaScope())->remove($relation->getQuery(), $relation->getRelated());
}])
->whereHas('funcaoEmpresa', function($query) use ($colaborador){
    $query->withoutGlobalScope('EmpresaScope')
        ->where('id', $colaborador['funcao_empresa_id']);
});
```

the `$query` variable inside the `whereHas` is just a `queryBuilder` instance, you can execute the `withoutGlobalScope` to it. It works because I had to use it in my project, I think it did not work on the OP case because it was an old version

Comment: Please explain your answer and why it works

Comment: the `$query` variable inside the whereHas is just a queryBuilder instance you can execute the withoutGlobalScope to it. It works because I had to use it in my project, I think it did not work on the OP case because it was an old version

Comment: Thanks for clarification, can you please add this to the answer and not as a comment, people generaly do not read comments.