# Laravel request validation throwing HttpResponseException in version 5.2

Tags: php, validation, laravel, exception

I'm trying to update Laravel from version 5.1 to 5.2 in my project, I have followed this [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) from the documentation, but now I'm getting this HttpResponseException when a validation fails

```
 * Handle a failed validation attempt.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException
 */
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException($this->response(
        $this->formatErrors($validator)
    ));
}
```

In 5.1, the framework redirected to the previous url automatically with the validation errors.

This is my validation request

```
namespace domain\funcao\formRequest;

use autodoc\Http\Requests\Request;

class StoreFuncaoRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'codigo' => 'required|max:255|unique:funcao,codigo,'.$this->input('id').',id,deleted_at,NULL',
            'nome' => 'required|max:255|unique:funcao,nome,'.$this->input('id').',id,deleted_at,NULL'
        ];
    }
}
```

I have already updated my Exceptions Handler according to the guide

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\ValidationException\ValidationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
    ];
    ...
}
```

Did someone had this problem??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause for this error, I was calling `PrettyPageHandler` from [Whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops) manually in my Exception Handler class.

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\ValidationException\ValidationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
    ];

    ...

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        // I just needed to remove this call to get rid of the problem
        if (config('app.debug'))
        {
            return $this->renderExceptionWithWhoops($e);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception using Whoops.
     * 
     * @param  \Exception $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function renderExceptionWithWhoops(Exception $e)
    {
        $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
        $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler());

        return new \Illuminate\Http\Response(
            $whoops->handleException($e),
            $e->getStatusCode(),
            $e->getHeaders()
        );
    }    
}
```

I'm still using Whoops, but now automatically through [Laravel Exceptions](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Exceptions)

Comment: for laravel 5.2 to keep using whoops, check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/whoops-20-laravel-52

Answer (score 1):

This was the first question I came across when I had this problem although for me it was with [Sentry](https://sentry.io) not Whoops.

Here's a couple of exceptions and how I dealt with them:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Your Session has Expired');
    }
    if ($e instanceof HttpResponseException) {
        return $e->getResponse();
    }
    return response()->view('errors.500', [
        'sentryID' => $this->sentryID,
    ], 500);
}
```

I handle the `HttpResponseException` by simply returning the response the same way the `ExceptionHandler` class does.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is, just write your business logics inside the protected failedValidation() inside your custom FormRequest class like follows

```
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

/**
* [failedValidation [Overriding the event validator for custom error response]]
* @param  Validator $validator [description]
* @return [object][object of various validation errors]
*/
public function failedValidation(Validator $validator) { 
     // write your business logic here otherwise it will give same old JSON response
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422)); 
}
```